# Why do humans need pillow to sleep better?

Tags: human-biology, human-evolution

As far as I know, no animal sleeps with a pillow/support under their heads. Why then do we need to keep a pillow?

Comment: Many, many animals make beddings and nests. Not unique to humans at all.

Comment: Yes agreed. But specifically do they have to use a support for their necks?

Comment: humans can sleep fine without pillows.

Comment: Our cat does it all the time ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is because the pillows keep the head align with body making it easier for the spine to maintain its natural curve. It reduces the tension in the lower dorsal region of neck. Many animals are found to be using pillow like substitutes for the same reason.

Comment: Which animals  .?

Comment: @YasirSadiq mamals in general use pilows most often their front legs/paws humans too putting our arm under our head while we sleep.